# TextView doesn't change to the new setted text

Tags: java, android, textview, onclicklistener

I've an Android app that has a login capabilities, and the login box has a `TextView` that displays messages to the user when trying to login(ie. wrong name, wrong pass, etc..).

I have two methods, the first one check if the fields is filled or not, and if filled it redirects the app to the second method that will check the user/pass from the local server.
the problem is when resetting the text in the second method, as when i set the text at the first method everything is OK, but when changing it in the second method it doesn't change, I can set it like million times in the first method and everything going well, another thing is when i set the text at the first time from the second method it works perfectly.

**Hint1**: this first method is the `onClick` method of an `OnClickListener`.
**Hint2**: the printed log is prented like million times in the logcat so the while condition verified

```
public class Login extends Activity {

public EditText user, pw;
public TextView errorMessage;
private static String response = null;
private static String data;
```

**the first method :**

```
public void onClick(View v) {

            if (v == login) {

                String userName = Login.this.user.getText().toString();
                String Password = Login.this.pw.getText().toString();

                if (userName.equals(null_string)
                        || Password.equals(null_string)) {
                    errorMessage.setText(R.string.request);
                } else {
                    protocol = protocol_login;

                    boolean status = false;
                    try {
                        status = checkLogin(userName, Password);
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    if (status) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                                MainPage.class);
                        go(intent);
                    } else {
                        errorMessage.setText(R.string.login_error);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
```

**the second method:**

```
private String connect(String data) throws UnknownHostException,
        IOException, JSONException {

    setData(data);
    Thread connect = new Thread(new ConnectToServer(getData()));
    connect.start();
    while (response == null) {
        System.out.println("waiting");
        errorMessage.setText(R.string.waiting);
    }
    return response;

}
}
```

Comment: Please post your full code including your declaration of TextView?

Comment: waht You Want To Do?Take USer Name And Password take from edittext and than you want to post on server?

Comment: plz update your full code.

Comment: Is your Log ever printed ? Response is probably a global and never null

Comment: another thing: you are setting the text over and over again, on the UIThread. I'm surprised it doesn't crash.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang yea i forgot to tell that, that log printed many many times

Comment: @Octopus ok i added the declarations

Comment: @ishu i added the declarations

Comment: What You Want to Do Take user name And Password From EditTeXt And Post It On WebService? Yes Or No

Comment: @ishu yes,i send them to the server to check if they are matching a valid pair, and waiting for the server response, by the way i healed setting the text everytime in the while loop

Comment: ya ok than why you do all thing on button click just make one function and call on button click and no need to make two function for edittext epmty or not becoz when u call webservice and edit text value null thn u got response from server like "username is not avilabel"

Comment: pls post your logcaT ALSO

Comment: hey MRefaat Show my Ans I hope It Helps you.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies in the fact that in the second method you are trying to update the GUI while actually being a second thread.

U can use the [runOnUIThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method

```
Activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           errorMessage.setText(R.string.waiting);
        }
});
while (response == null) {
    System.out.println("waiting");  
}
```

U also shouldn't set the text in a while-loop if the text isn't changing so you don't use unnecessary resources.

Comment: but i don't want it to run on ui thread as always, because there are times i want this textView to display another thing while running the ui thread

Comment: Everything that you want to display will need to take place on the UI thread. This code above only runs the update function on the UI thread while the networking code(or any calculations for example) will run in its own thread.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what exactly is causing your problem (you are blocking the UI thread somewhere), but there are better ways of getting a response from the server. You are essentially synchronously checking for an asynchronous response (below), because you are continuously polling whether `response` is not null.

Android has a useful class called [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html). You give an AsyncTask some work to do on a background thread (what `ConnectToServer(..)` does), and when it is done, another method on the AsyncTask (called `onPostExecute(..)`) is called. The benefit of this over your approach is that it handles all the threading for you, and doesn't poll. There is also a method [`onPreExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPreExecute%28%29) which you would set your waiting text in.

N.B. checking synchronously for an asynchronous response

What I mean by this is that the response can come back at any time (asynchronously), yet you are checking for it at any point you can (synchronously). This is going to waste valuable resources on the CPU - you should get the response to ***tell*** you when it is finished rather than continually ***ask*** whether it is.

Comment: I just don't want the program continue running while it doesn't get a response from the server

Answer (score 1):

First, these two string variables are declared globally:

```
String userName,Password
```

Try this easy Asyntask method:

```
    private class SetDataOfWebService extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Boolean> {
            ProgressDialog pDialog;
            boolean success = false;
            ConnectivityManager connectivity;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MailSettings.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Please Wait..");
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
                    success = true;

                      if (userName.length()>0 || Password.length()>0) {
                           status = checkLogin(userName, Password);
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          errorMessage.setText(R.string.request);
                      }
                } else {
                    success = false;
                }
                return success;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
                if (result) {
                    if (status) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(),
                                    MainPage.class);
                            go(intent);
                        } else {
                            errorMessage.setText(R.string.login_error);
                        }
                } else {
                    return;
                }

            }

            public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
                connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                if (connectivity != null) {
                    NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();

                    if (info != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                            Log.i("Class", info[i].getState().toString());
                            if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

    }

////Calling This Function On Button CLick Like This
userName = Login.this.user.getText().toString();
Password = Login.this.pw.getText().toString();
new SetDataOfWebService().execute();
```